# Unit testing a RecyclerView Adapter throws NullPointerException when accessing mObservables

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-recyclerview

My view model holds a very simple recyclerview adapter

When I try to send it messages (which in turn calls `notifyDatasetChanged`) it throws an exception like so

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyChanged(RecyclerView.java:11996)
at
```

the problem is that the `mObservers` variable from `AdapterDataObservable` is null

the thing is that this extends `Observable<AdapterDataObserver>` which in turn defines `mObservers` as

```
protected final ArrayList<T> mObservers = new ArrayList<T>();
```

so basically the moment my adapter is instantiated , it will call

```
private final AdapterDataObservable mObservable = new AdapterDataObservable();
```

(which is called by the way, mObservable is not null)

which in turn should call `mObservers = new ArrayList<T>();`

can someone explain why this is never called? or if there is a way to get past this problem?

as a side note the adapter is not mocked it is a solid object.

Edit:

Here is the code of the tests I'm using:

```
class LoginViewModelTest {

     private lateinit var vm: LoginViewModel

        @get:Rule
        val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

        @Before
        fun setUp() {

            whenever(settings.hasShownWelcome).thenReturn(false)
            whenever(settings.serverIp).thenReturn("http://127.0.0.1")

            //this is where the crash happens
            vm = LoginViewModel(settings, service, app, TestLog, TestDispatchers) { p -> permissionGranted }
        }
```

And below is the code that is tested:

```
class LoginViewModel(private val settings: ISettings, private val service: AppService, application: Application, l: ILog, dispatchers: IDispatchers, val permissionChecker: (String) -> Boolean) :  BaseViewModel(application, l, dispatchers)

    val stepAdapter :StepAdapter

    init {
        val maxSteps = calculateSteps()
        //after this assignment, during the normal run, the stepAdapter.mObservable.mObservers is an empty array
        //during unit tests, after this assignment it is null
        stepAdapter = StepAdapter(maxSteps) 
    }
```

Comment: you mean android unit test? no it is not, it is a normal unit test, junit test, or however they are called

Comment: this question does not feature any test at all, while it might be an instrumented test.

Comment: I have now added the exact part of the tests this behaviour is shown

Comment: Viewmodels are supposed to give us standarization, yet yours have more arguments than needed in the constructor and hold a reference to the view, the adapter should be in the view and the viewmodel should forward the data to it. Also, testing adapters is usually done with Espresso and testing the http reques should be 2 different tests.

Comment: I use that many arguments because I give access to interfaces for settings, api calls, coroutine dispatchers, and logging (which otherwise could be done using Dagger with which I do not have enough practice yet).


I use adapters in the view model because they allow me more control over what is shown in recyclers , I can directly add/remove/update items and if they are attached they will update their respective view , otherwise they do nothing.

Using livedata to update the adapter means that the whole adapter always gets updated, not just the changes

Answer (score 4):

I fixed mine by spying on the adapter and stubbing `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
    val spyAdapter = spyk(adapter)
    every { spyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() } returns Unit
    spyAdapter.changeItems(items)
    verify { spyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() }
```

Please, note that `changeItems` calls `notifyDataSetChanged` internally.

Comment: Apparently notifyDataSetChanged() returns void in Java, therefore returning Unit in kotlin didn't help, at least our recyclerview related dependencies are still based in Java, so it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if you have already found a solution or not, but this is for other people like me who ran into a similar problem:

make the test an **android test** (aka **instrumented test**) and **not** a unit test.

while i cannot fully explain why, it seems that when notifying an adapter about a change (`notifyItemChanged()`, `notifyDataSetChanged()` etc.) something about the inner logic of android requires an actual `RecyclerView`/adapter to receive the message.

once i moved my test from the `Test` folder to the `AndroidTest` folder, the problem was fixed.

P.S.

make sure to remove your old build configuration! android studio keeps referring to the old one (in the `Test` folder) and if you don't remove it you will receive a `classNotFound` error

Comment: no I didn't find a solution, I went a different way (iirc by injecting the adapter which was mocked on the constructor) , I know it would work for android tests, but I wanted to use unit tests for viewmodels since they are much faster

Comment: @Cruces can help understand how you solved the problem with unit test

Comment: My viewModel became `class LoginViewModel(private val settings: ISettings, private val service: AppService, application: Application, l: ILog, dispatchers: IDispatchers, val permissionChecker: (String) -> Boolean, val adapter:StepAdapter) :  BaseViewModel(application, l, dispatchers)` and when I start the tests I mock the adapter and inject it through the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem doing this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.N, Build.VERSION_CODES.O], application = AppTest::class)
class HomeAdapterTest {
```

Where the AppTest is am empty class.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instrad of `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)` and work fine for me... the sample code :

Inside `viewModel.fetchPokemonList()` function I use `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PokemonCardListTest {
    @Rule public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();

    @Mock Context context;
    @Mock LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner;
    @Mock public List<PokemonCard> pokemonCardList;
    private Repository repository;
    private Lifecycle lifecycle;
    private PokemonCardListViewModel viewModel;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);


        pokemonCardList = Arrays.asList(
                new PokemonCard("1" ,"Card1" , "Artist1"),
                new PokemonCard("2" ,"Card2" , "Artist2")
        );

        repository = new FakeRepository(pokemonCardList);

        lifecycle = new LifecycleRegistry(lifecycleOwner);
        viewModel = new PokemonCardListViewModel(context , repository);

    }

    @Test
    public void testSearch() {

        viewModel.fetchPokemonList("99");
        assertEquals(viewModel.getAdapter().getValue().getItemCount() , pokemonCardList.size());
    
        viewModel.fetchPokemonList("0");
        assertEquals(viewModel.getAdapter().getValue().getItemCount() , 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with the same problem. After researching the RecyclerView's code I implemented a way to mock `mObservable` and this issue was gone. Here is an example of to deceit the adapter(Kotlin):

```
val observersValueMock: ArrayList<AdapterDataObserver> = mock()
// Modifiers to set private final variables
val modifiersField = Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
modifiersField.isAccessible = true
// Get Recycler Adapter mObservable instance
val mObservableField = (generalAdapter::class.java.superclass as Class)
    .getDeclaredField("mObservable")
mObservableField.isAccessible = true
val observableValue = mObservableField.get(generalAdapter)

//observableValue is Observable<AdapterDataObserver>,
//which has variable mObservers of type ArrayList<AdapterDataObserver>
//Exactly 'mObservers' called when you call notifyDatasetChange. And 
//because you don't attach adapter to a real RecyclerView, it's null.
//Need to set an empty array or mock to get rid of NPE  
val observersField = observableValue.javaClass.superclass.getDeclaredField("mObservers")
observersField.isAccessible = true
//Allow to set final variables
modifiersField.setInt(observersField, observersField.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())
observersField.set(observableValue, observersValueMock)
```

Hope this code may help or at least will give a clue of how to mock what you need